# How to get Test Result in Custom Code Activity in TfvcTemplate.12

Tags: workflow

I want to add a if statement to the work flow diagram in the tfcvtemplate.12 after "Run VS Test Runner" and the condition should be if all tests succeded but i cannot find any variables in the new templates.

Anyone who have done this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the tests fail then it will throw an exception and enter the catch block, if they pass it will go onto the next activity:

[image]

Comment: do you know also how i get the output folder (string in argument on my code activity) where the builded website is located? I need the patch to the "_PublishedWebsites" folder such I can copy it to external source with my code activity. I tried DropLocation, but gave me error:Could not find a part of the path 'C:\lightrail\Services\Mms\BuildProvisioner\Tools\SingleFolder'

Comment: No, my customisation of Templates is usually done against WinForms. It could be `BinariesDirectory` or similar.